# Is there a way to specify alternative cluster region in DataprocCreateClusterOperator?

Tags: airflow

I have two region to create Dataproc cluster. Is there a way to give alternative cluster region if cluster creation fails in a region?

Let's say I have two regions: region_1 and region_2

I will first try to create cluster in region_1. Let's say it failed due to resource issue. I am looking for some mechanism where cluster creation will be redirected to region_2.